# Is there a way to make tkinter apps bigger on high dpi displays?

Tags: python, tkinter, fedora, dpi

When I launch a python application with a gui on my macbook pro running fedora 21 - the tkinter gui is very small.

Is there any way I can scale this up so its useful?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, see [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132203/scaling-of-tkinter-python-tk-gui-in-4k-38402160-resolution).

You could also [Google "python tkinter scale up DPI"](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+tkinter+scale+up+DPI), which gives [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132203/scaling-of-tkinter-python-tk-gui-in-4k-38402160-resolution) as the [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132203/scaling-of-tkinter-python-tk-gui-in-4k-38402160-resolution).

---

Essentially, (as [the other question outlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132203/scaling-of-tkinter-python-tk-gui-in-4k-38402160-resolution)), you need a *scaling factor*.  This is based around an idealised 72 DPI.  So, for a 300 DPI display, you may wish to set a factor of around `4.0` (technically `4.166`):

> ```
> root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 4.0)
> ```