# Python TkInter - Windows 10 desktop scaling (HDPI) is affecting canvas' geomtery

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've written a few very basic TkInter apps for testing purposes - basically filling screen with 2 colors, and it's working as expected when my screen dpi saclling is set to 100%; but when it's different it affects proportions of rectangles in my canvas. for example here I want to have exactly half of screen filed with one color and second with another:

```
class TkSplitScreen(object):
    UPDATE_TIME = 1

    def __init__(self, rect, color1, color2, communication_queue, vertical=False):
        logging.info(" -- Starting TkSolidColor app")
        self._communication_queue = communication_queue
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.winfo_toplevel().title("TkSplitScreen")
        gemetry = "%dx%d+%d+%d" % (rect.w, rect.h, rect.x, rect.y)
        logging.info(" -- geometry: %s", gemetry)
        self.tk.geometry(gemetry)
        self.tk.attributes('-topmost', 1)
        self.tk.state('zoomed')
        self.tk.config(cursor="none")  # remove cursor
        self.tk.resizable(False, False)
        self.tk.overrideredirect(True)
    #    self.tk.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        hex_color1 = '#%02x%02x%02x' % color1
        hex_color2 = '#%02x%02x%02x' % color2
        logging.info(" -- color: %s", hex_color1)
        logging.info(" -- color: %s", hex_color2)
        canvas = Canvas(self.tk)
        if vertical:
            canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, rect.w // 2, rect.h, fill=hex_color1, outline=hex_color1)
            canvas.create_rectangle(rect.w // 2, 0, rect.w, rect.h, fill=hex_color2, outline=hex_color2)
        else:
            canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, rect.w, rect.h // 2, fill=hex_color1, outline=hex_color1)
            canvas.create_rectangle(0, rect.h // 2, rect.w, rect.h, fill=hex_color2, outline=hex_color2)
        canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.tk.after(self.UPDATE_TIME, self.read_queue)
        self.tk.mainloop()

    def read_queue(self):
        if not self._communication_queue.empty():
            request = self._communication_queue.get()

            if request == 'EXIT':
                logging.info(" -- Exit request received. Closing TkSplitScreen process")
                self.tk.quit()
                return

        self.tk.after(self.UPDATE_TIME, self.read_queue)
```

Where for my 4k screen i give as rect 3840x2160 (at 0, 0). Is it possible to tell OS that I don't want to scale out my TkApp? Or do I need to somehow recalculate physical resolution to some virtual points? (I was assuming that what you give to create_rectangle is in pixels not some virtual points)

Comment: You could either use [tkinters scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34132203) and [detect the scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63469642) or use [SetProcessDpiAwareness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44422362)

Comment: I've seen `tkinters scaling` before and it wasn't helpful. What helped me was `SetProcessDpiAwareness`, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can DPI scaling be enabled/disabled programmatically on a per-session basis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398075/can-dpi-scaling-be-enabled-disabled-programmatically-on-a-per-session-basis)