# Python tkinter button font is getting pixelated in bigger sizes

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, fonts

First of all, thank you for trying to help me out. I am currently programming my first GUI with tkinter and i try to create buttons with big fonts, cause i want to create a program for visually impaired people. Sadly I have two problems i can't solve with the internet on my own ..

This is the relevant part of my code: (sorry for the german variables)

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
import tkinter.messagebox

class Oberflaeche(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        MyFont = font.Font(family='times', size=50)

        self.close_window = tkinter.Button(self, font=MyFont, text="Programm \nbeenden", command=self.close_window, bg="white", height = 3, width = 18, bd=3, relief="solid")
        self.close_window.pack()

    def close_window(self): 
        root.destroy()
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Prototyp MVP")
root.minsize(width=300, height=300)
root.configure(background='white')
oberflaeche = Oberflaeche(master=root)
oberflaeche.mainloop()
```

when I try to change the font tkFont.Font is not working. There is the Error:
NameError: name 'tkFont' is not defined

That is the reason I tryed font.Font. But no matter how I change the font family or type, it always looks awful and pixelated....

[Picture of the failed Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgH6z.png)
I am using python 3.5.5, Ubuntu 16.04 and tk 8.6.8.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spyder(python 3.6) here is the result;
i.hizliresim.com/6NgZlW.jpg
Maybe because of version?
Actually your program is working succesfully ı did not change any codes ı tried on my pc and the result is perfect(Win10 Spyder(Python 3.6).)

Comment: I am using jupyter notebook. Maybe that is the problem ? I will try spyder. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i am also used to Jupyter notebook and i was trying with VS Code everything is working well. I suggest you trying to play around with scaling and let me know is it working for you?

[**Scaling of Tkinter GUI in 4k (3840*2160) resolution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132203/scaling-of-tkinter-gui-in-4k-38402160-resolution)

> **Results**

**Jupyter**

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

**VS Code**

[image: VS Code]