# Tkinter Widget Size Issues

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

EDIT: I found the solution! My xorg settings were all wacky because I have an ultrawide monitor, and it had no idea what size (and therefore dpi) my monitor was. Explicitly setting the display and font dpi in X's settings fixed the rendering in *all* GUI's.

ORIGINAL:

When I run any tkinter program, many of the widgets render at around 1/2 size, especially text. Why is this happening? My window manager is Window Maker, and I'm running the latest version of Tcl/Tk.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

My code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(text="Name")
entry = tk.Entry()
button = tk.Button(text="Submit")

label.pack()
entry.pack()
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Window manager: `Window Maker 0.95.0`
Tk: `tk 8.6.10-2`

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34133102/5317403) and it may help.

Comment: That somewhat worked. The widgets still look wacky, but that’s a different issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tkinter you can only change the size of a label with the font atribute, and same goes for the text inside the button. The button size can be changed  with the width and height atribute.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

label = Label(text="Name", font='Helvetica 15')
entry = Entry()
button = Button(text="Submit",font ='Helvetica 15', height="3", width="10")

label.pack(pady = 5) # add pady inside the pack
entry.pack()
button.pack(pady = 5)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i have updated with code and explanation , hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try this out when I get back to my computer

Comment: sure , if it works don't forget to tick it :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the rendering is still wacky. Everything increased in size 4x, but spacing inside the widgets was still off. I think it's my old WM causing the issues, not Tk. Thanks for the help!

Comment: i added the missing part now it should be just fine

Comment: It seems that the overall scaling is the issue. Using `window.tk.call("tk", "scaling", 2.0)` works. Thanks for your help! I should probably move to a newer WM.